# $string[i] does not return the i:th character

Tags: php

I'm writing a function intended to sanitize a poorly formatted string which the php script will receive from an outside source. The problem with this string is that every odd numbered byte is zero, so what the function does is that it pushes every even numbered byte to a new array. [Code](http://pastebin.com/LLdZq7mW):

```
$serverInfoClean = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($serverInfo); $i++ ) // Remove every odd numbered byte
{
    if ($i & 1) // Odd index
    {
        // Do nothing
    } 
    else // Even index
    {
        array_push($serverInfoClean, $serverInfo[i]);
        echo $i . ' ' . $serverInfo[i] . '<br/>'; // Debug
    }
}
```

The debug line is there so I can see in my browser which values it returns. It returns the first character in the string every single time.

Comment: In PHP, variables are denoted with a `$` prefix; `i` is not a variable, only `$i` is.

Comment: ...I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$serverInfoClean = array();
$end = strlen($serverInfo);
for ($i = 0; $i < $end; $i++ ) // Remove every odd numbered byte
{
    if ($i & 1) // Odd index
    {
            // Do nothing
    }
    else // Even index
    {
            array_push($serverInfoClean, $serverInfo[$i]);
            echo $i . ' ' . $serverInfo[$i] . '<br/>'; // Debug
    }
}
```

Comment: You put strlen outside the loop so that it doesn't have to be evaluated at each iteration, correct?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should jump to the conclusion that it is a "poorly formatted string". It sounds a lot like your string has been encoded as UTF-16 so that it will also work with non-ASCII (Unicode) characters.

You can instead use the [multibyte string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) to correctly handle the multibyte characters.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$serverInfo[i]` with `$serverInfo[$i]`